# Верстка элементов разной высоты в две колонки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Как сверстать 2 колонки с элементами разной высоты? Учитывая что при адаптиве нужно будет менять их порядок. То есть делать два флекс блока с flex-direction: column - не вариант, так как со второй колонки нужно будет перенести в первую!
[image: десктоп]

[image: планшет]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: можно для разных размеров экранов указывать разный порядок